# Unable to install Cordova CLI

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic2

When I'm trying to install the Cordova CLI with "sudo npm install -g cordova", everything seems to work fine:

```
/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@6.1.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── ansi@0.3.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
├── update-notifier@0.5.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, string-length@1.0.1, repeating@1.1.3, semver-diff@2.1.0, chalk@1.1.3, configstore@1.4.0, latest-version@1.0.1)
├── cordova-common@1.2.0 (cordova-registry-mapper@1.1.15, unorm@1.4.1, underscore@1.8.3, q@1.4.1, semver@5.1.0, osenv@0.1.3, bplist-parser@0.1.1, shelljs@0.5.3, glob@5.0.15, elementtree@0.1.6, plist@1.2.0)
└── cordova-lib@6.1.1 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, opener@1.4.1, properties-parser@0.2.3, semver@4.3.6, nopt@3.0.6, dep-graph@1.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, xcode@0.8.0, request@2.47.0, cordova-serve@1.0.0, aliasify@1.9.0, init-package-json@1.9.3, cordova-app-hello-world@3.10.0, tar@1.0.2, cordova-js@4.1.4, npm@2.15.5)
```

But my system information stays the same:

```
Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.6
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.25
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.15
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.4.4
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

I also tried to install a specific package of the Cordova CLI with "npm install -g cordova@6.1.1" and to unistall and reinstall Cordova, but I still get:

```
Cordova CLI: Not installed
```

Comment: Have you installed codova cli globally? To check, you can issue this command in terminal 'which cordova'. It should return a path where cordova cli is located. If not, you will have to add NPM global path to your shell. Hope it helps

Comment: Which version of npm are you using ?

Comment: @Gandhi Yes I have installed Cordova CLI globally.

Comment: @schankam version 2.15.1

Comment: @untmat Are you able to execute 'cordova -version' command in terminal and get the version?

Comment: @Gandhi 'cordova -version' returns '6.1.1'

Comment: @untmat I suggest  you to have a look at this link - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/756 Its mostly a permission issue and sudo should do the trick. Check comment from biruwon and agbottan in the link. Keep us posted.

Comment: @Gandhi Thanks a lot! When I'm running 'sudo ionic info' I get `Cordova CLI: 6.1.1`

Comment: @untmat Glad it worked. Have posted the answer. Accept the same so that it can be helpful for others too. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look at this [link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/756).It's mostly a permission issue and sudo should do the trick. Try executing the following command,

```
sudo ionic info
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using nvm 8.1.3 and then installing Cordova with `sudo npm install -g cordova` command worked for me.